# css - Printed page text goes outside the block on page break

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

So i have this generated page i want to print - http://hubog-2017.com/print_prog_en

I break the page after each table. In the second table, one of the texts is too long and it breaks into two pages (Pages 2 and 3). Now the problem is that the text gets outside its TD and i see it on the THEAD.

[image]

I tried using word-breaks and padding's with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get a partial solution by adding this CSS:
Its not exactly how i wanted it to look but at least the text is not breaking...

```
@page {
    size: A4;   
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }  
}
```